# delegated Admin

Tags: community, administration, delegated-admin

Can anyone please let me know how to use delegated admin feature which is in Salesforce. I have made an user as delegated admin and added some profiles where those profiles can be controlled by the delgated admin. Can any one let me know how it can be applicable in salesforce communities.

Answer (score 2):

One of the Communities capabilities that everyone wishes to use is the Delegated Admin permissions so that Community License Users can manage users that belong to their account.

During my investigation, I have tried several things, according to Salesforce Communities documentation, including: 
1. creating a permission set that grants a Community Licensed User the Delegated External User Administration permission 
2. creating a profile with the Delegated External User Administration permission granted

I have attached some articles to this case which you may find helpful and reference what I explained above:

Granting Super User Access to Users in Your Community
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&language=en_US

Communities User Licenses
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Customizing Communities
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_customize.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's a doozy - you need to ensure you do not have "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" checked to ensure you can find the "Delegated External User Profiles related list" as defined on the help document https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_DPUA.htm